# CakePHP - Third Part Assignments

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

Sorry if the Title misses what i'm aiming at, but had no clue how to name this. Here's my Quest:

I have a single Cart, holding multiple Items (1:n) which are belonging to prices (1:1).

The Relations between Items and Prices are working as well:

```
class Item extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = 'Price';
}

class Price extends AppModel {

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Item' => array(
                'className' => 'Item',
                'foreignKey' => 'id'
            )
    );
}
```

But now i make a select (find) of a cart and want those items included, which is also working as well:

```
class CartItem extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cart_items';

    public $belongsTo = array('Item', 'Address');
}
```

But what i really need is to get those prices of each item, which is not working ($result in afterFind()-Callback in Item-Model does not include the assigned prices & afterFind()-Callback in Price-Model is not called when finding a cart)..

what am i missing here?

**/EDIT: Recent Changes:**

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
}


class CartsController extends AppController {

public function getCart() {
$cart = ClassRegistry::init('CartItem')->find('all', array(
                    'contain' => array(
                        'Item' => array(
                            'Price'
                        ),
                        'Address'
                    ),
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'id_cart' => $cart['Cart']['id']
                    )
                ));
}
```

The above changes cause that i'll get a Price into a found Item but only into the last one thats found.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your actual `find()`, but I suspect you're not setting an appropriate `'recursive'` param or are not using `'contain'`.

I prefer using the containable behaviour enabled from AppModel:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$cartItem = $this->CartItem->find(
  'first',
  array(
    'contain' => array(
      'Item' => array(
        'Price'
      ),
      'Address'
    ),
    'conditions' => array('CartItem.id' => 123)
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works partly. - BUT: In 5 Items only the last one selected has the Price included now. See my Code, i inserted the changes and the FIND

Comment: In Price's $belongsTo relationship to Item you're using a foreignKey of 'id', this would normally be 'item_id'. If you really don't have a foreign key and are enforcing both Item and Price to have the same id value, then in Item's $hasOne for Price you also need to specify the foreign key because CakePHP will be expecting to find Price.item_id.